# Smaller number of rows to PK+AI

Tags: mysql

Is it normal that my table has a value of AI greater than the number of rows?

Never deleted any rows.

[image: DB-INFO]

Comment: Perfectly normal. I'd worry if it was the other way around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it not too likely, but you could have changed the auto_increment value through an [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) operation:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value
```

I would not worry too much about this, since the whole point of an auto_increment field is to provide a unique number of records. It was never meant to be fully consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone attempts to insert a row, and the insert fails for any reason, the AUTO_INCREMENT value will increment, but no row will be inserted. It is completeley normal.